# How do I clean an angular 2+ project so it can be zipped and emailed

Tags: angular, npm

I am new to angular and npm. I have a project I have been working on and would like to zip and email it. Is there an npm command to leave packages.json and clean the node-modules directory so that someone who gets the zip can unzip and run "npm install". Or is this just something you need to do from command line and remove all child directories under node-modules?

I think the only directory I need to clean is node_modules is that correct. Any help you can provide would be appreciated.

Comment: `rm -rf node_modules`? Why do you use zip and email to share a project. Use a version control system, like git(hub).

Comment: In your project directory, `ctrl+a` , ignore `node_modules` folder, zip the rest \o/ ... -1 for the question though ..

Comment: because it is not something to publicly share. the -1 is ok because in reading responses i learn

Comment: Then use a private repository. They're free at bitbucket.

Comment: Adding to the `publicly sharing` point, you can use free private repositories with visual studio team services ... or paid with GitHub

Comment: But is the command line option the way to clean the node-modules or is there an npm command

Comment: Why would you want to clean and install them everytime on your local machine?

Comment: I want to zip and email them hence the clean to remove things that running npm install will re-install because the packages.json file is left as it was. I don't want to use a repo, but thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: @J.D. npm does that too.

Comment: +1 I have the same exact problem.  I have a number of projects, I want to remove all generated code and imported binaries, and keep only what is necessary to eventually recompile and run the project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

npm clean

npm cache clean

Or

you can delete the local node modules folder to zip wherein package json would be helper for same other folks.

Comment: Doesn't npm clean only remove unused dependencies https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-clean

Comment: I am not looking to do anything to the cache just the local node-modules

Comment: I think you are right about delete node-modules and dist. That's why I am asking the question wanted to see if I had missed something

Comment: With `npm install` you can bring back the *node_modules* folder.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my colleague I have managed to do it easily using *rimraf*:

1. Execute this command: *npm install -g rimraf* inside your angular project
2. Then execute: *rimraf node_modules* inside your angular project (NOTE: node_modules is the name of directory that contains node modules)